# Detect the language of a text is english in PDF or DOC files

Tags: c#

Requirement is that i want to identify that the text written in PDF or Doc is english or non english. if i got a single word of (turiskh, french,arabic and etc.) have to avoid the whole documnet

its urgent plz give me sample code for this functionality

Comment: If none of the answers so far helped can you atleast say why they are wrong? Also you haven't marked any question you've asked as answered. Looks to me you are either extremely demanding and want people to write a complete example you can just copy paste. Or you are just using this website to do your work for you without having to immerse yourself in this website.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on Google Translate API, only free service who could do this for you what I know. Otherwise I can only see the solution of having your own dictionary etc.. But thats a different story

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use [LangId](http://langid.net/identify-language-from-api.html). However there are some restrictions:

> To use our API in live websites or services we suggest you to apply for a free API key, using the below form. The API key expands your developing possibilities allowing you to do up till 1,000 requests per hour (~720,000 per month).

I don't think this will solve your 'single word' issue however. I believe if the text has 6 words English and 4 words in another language it will see the text as English since that language is mainly used in the file. I haven't looked at the API myself though so there might be some solutions for that.

Hope it is of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the detect function of Google's Translate API could help you:

http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html#language_detect

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for single words.

Is "the" an English word? Well, yes, but it's also a Danish word (meaning tea). Does the word Schadenfreude indicate a non-english text? Not necessarily, it all depends on the context.

Adding to the list of APIs that support language determination, Bing API has a call that will determine the language for an array of strings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512412.aspx

Hope this helps somewhat.